# Sending html email with image: absolute url or attach image?

Tags: python, html, django, email, amazon-ses

I am sending html email with several images in it. My project is written in Python and Django and invokes web service to send the email(I can pass to the web service the html and attachments). The web service is in other part of the project and is implemented in Java and uses Amazon SES.

Which is the best approach for the html images?
To store them on my web server and link them with absolute URLs or to send the images as attachments and embed them in the html?

Do all email clients support absolute URLs for images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest attaching images for clarity, but if you really want to save on used bandwidth and send lots of emails, it's better to send the URL..... If you are sure it won't change.